# Recursion: In how many ways we can tile a rectangle with size of $1\times 10$ without two adjacent red floor tiles?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion, tiling

This is the question:

We have unlimited floor tiles in the colors red or blue. Every color comes in the size of $1\times 1$ or $1 \times 2.$

In how many ways we can tile a **rectangle** with size of $1\times 10$ without two adjacent red floor tiles?
What is the recursion formula for that problem and that are the start conditions?

---

*I have tried to think about a solution like this:*

- for **rectangle** size of $1 \times 1$ we have $2$ options: red or blue $1 \times 1$ floor tile
- for **rectangle** size of $1\times 2$ we have $3$ options: red & blue $1 \times 1,$ $2$ blue $1 \times 1$ or $1$ blue $1 \times 2$

But later then I got stucked with comming up with a solution to Typical Polynomym

Comment: I have edited my question and also changed triangle to rectangle... more so, the phrase "two adjacent red floor tiles" signify a condition that says: you can not place two red tiles one next to each other

Comment: Exactly [ | | | | | | | | | ] like this - you can place in blank spaces floor tiles in the size  and color above

Comment: It seems to me that the thing to do is solve the problem (manually, counting by hand, with no attempt at elegance) when the row is 3 tiles long. Then see what happens if the row is 4 tiles long, then 5 tiles long. I would say at this point it is time to stop the manual work, look for a pattern re each row, form a hypothesis, and then try to prove a hypothesis. If you do this, and show your work, you will probably get a positive response from mathSE.

Comment: Two other suggestions: (1) This problem is *similar* to the Stars and Bars problem discussed at https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/.  Frankly, because you have a **variable** number of red tiles to use, and because you can use either $1x1$ blue tiles or $1x2$ blue tiles, and because we are only talking about a row of size 10, I'm not sure if this website is worth your exploring for this problem. ...see next comment

Comment: (2) In accordance with my earlier comment about manual exploration through row length = 5, I would consider for a given row length of either $2k$ or $(2k+1)$, breaking the exploration up into $(k+1)$ cases, where for $r ~\in ~\{0,1,2,\cdots, k\}$, your row contains exactly $r$ 1x2 tiles.  Also, with respect to recursion, I would **consider** trying to recurse between $n$ and $(n+2)$, rather than between $n$ and $(n+1).$

Comment: Also, however you recurse, [i.e. between $n$ and $(n+1)$ or between $n$ and $(n+2)$] you might consider attempting to break the current row tiling into 2 cases : case (A): rightmost tile is red, case (B): rightmost tile is blue.

Comment: I answered a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558056/recurrence-relation-about-flag-pole/2558065#2558065).  You should be able to use coupled recurrences-how many ways to make a rectangle of length $n$ that ends in red and how many that end in blue.

Answer (score 1):

Notation: $R(1,1)$ is a $1\times 1$ red tile, $R(1,2)$ is a $1\times 2$ red tile and so on.

There are two reasons for which the question seems awkward.

1. What does *how many ways* mean?  More precisely, when tiling a $1\times 2$ rectangle, $R(1,1)+B(1,1)$ is the same as $B(1,1)+R(1,1)$?  Looking at your count, it seems that you would like to consider them as representing one tiling.  My answer below considers them as being distinct.  To state it differently: **I consider no symmetry that identifies two tilings.**
2. Your example for a $1\times 2$ rectangle is incorrect whatever way of counting you consider; you forgot the $R(1,2)$ construction.

A solution sketch.  A tiling for a $1\times n$ rectangle is considered as having, either a *final* $R(1,i)$ or a $B(1,i)$ tile.  Denote $r_n$ the number of tiling ending with a red one, and $b_n$ the number of those ending with a blue one.  We need to determine these two sequences.

We have, after some moments of thought about the final tile,
$b_n=b_{n-1}+r_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+r_{n-2}$ and $r_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$.  Moreover, $b_1=1$ and $b_2=3$, and $r_1=1$ and $r_2=2$.

To have our count, it is sufficient to determine $(b_n)_n$.  But using the two recurrent relations, $b_n=b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}+2b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}$ with the initial conditions
$b_{-3}=b_{-2}=b_{-1}=0$ and $b_0=1$.  This is the sequence
https://oeis.org/A123392.

For the $1\times 10$ problem, we obtain
$b_8=461$, $b_9=1068$, $b_{10}=2474$, and hence $r_{10}=1529$.  The sum $b_{10}+r_{10}$ is the number we are looking for.

**Remark.** If we want to obtain the number of tilings after the identification by reflection in the "vertical" mediator of the $1\times 10$ rectangle, the study of the tilings of the $1\times 5$ rectangle is needed and some considerations about the action of the group $\{-1,1\}$ (of the reflection) on the tilings of the $1\times 10$ rectangle.